# SQL-Server Password Encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, password-encryption

I am creating a database for a website I've just developed but I need to encrypt my passwords.

I've never encrypted passwords before and I don't know how to do it, I've searched google and a lot of websites but all they do is confuse me.

Here is my Sproc:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
Username Nvarchar(200) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Password Nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
EmailPassword Nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
UsernamePassword Nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Usernames(
Username Nvarchar(200) FOREIGN KEY(Username) REFERENCES USERS(Username),
Usernames Nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(500)
)
CREATE TABLE Emails(
Username Nvarchar(200) FOREIGN KEY(Username) REFERENCES USERS(Username),
Passwords Nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(500)
)
CREATE TABLE Passwords(
Username Nvarchar(200) FOREIGN KEY(Username) REFERENCES USERS(Username),
Usernames Nvarchar(300) NOT NULL,
Description nvarchar(500)
)
```

I would like to encrypt the columns that contain NOT NULL accept the username column

Comment: Use a hash and a random salt. Here's a nice article: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont store the password directly, not even encrypted. Use a salted hash.

Check out

- [Secure Salted Password Hashing - How to do it Properly](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)
- [Strong Password Hashing with SQL Server](http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2009/09/19/strong-password-hashing-with-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: How would I go about this