# SQL Server query for case sensitive password checking

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

In my application I am sending password to database, let's say my password is `PassworD123`. Now this is giving me proper value, but when I am using `password123`, it's also giving me the proper value. So how to check for case sensitive data in SQL Server? Any demo code will help.

I had use collate tag it work case sensitive in local server but when we upload it provide error like invalid password, how can solve this problem?

Comment: looks like you're storing your password in plain readable text, which you shouldn't. take a look at the links here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25136157/57475

Answer (score -1):

You can use Hashbytes function with md5 algorithm:

SELECT UserId 
       FROM Users 
       WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'PassworD123'), 2)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'password123'), 2)