# Is there any way to encrypt SQL Server Password?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to encrypt my SQL Server SA password for some highly security purpose, how can I do this? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: SA password is not a thing you ever want to write somewhere. What is your reason?

Comment: I want to keep more secure my database and i didn't found any encryption option while creating SQL Server password.

Comment: Still not clear to me where and why you want to store the password? Paswords are best stored in human memory, where it is well encripted.

Comment: You generally never use passwords to access the SQL server, and you absolutely never have the SA password in production use (not for people, not for scheduled tasks, not for services, etc.). Authentication in production use is done via Windows user accounts that have appropriate access rights (Windows-integrated authentication). There is no need to "encrypt" the SA password.

Comment: Thou shalt never use SA login to access thine database from application or web server - this way you don't have write it into config files or application code.

Comment: Actually, I got the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136102/sql-server-password-encryption